# Structure of WAR project with Javascript tests and debug files

Tags: web-applications, gradle, war, project-structure

I am working on an existing project. It is a web application with a backend
written in Java and a number of static images, HTML and Javascript resources
packaged as a WAR file.

The project is fairly old and has a completely custom structure in terms of:

- directory structure,
- dependency management (a bunch of jars in a directory, no explicit dependency
  on a specific build like with Maven),
- build tasks (compilation and creation of WAR file, with a custom Ant script
  setting up the classpath, copying some files and not others when building the
  WAR file, etc...).

I want to modernize this structure and migrate the project to Gradle. I would
like to stick to the default directory structure and build tasks as much as
possible.

Part of this means creating src/main/webapp, and moving all static resources
under that directory. The default build tasks will package everything under
src/main/webapp to the root of the WAR file.

The problem is that with the Javascript code being non-trivial, there are a
number of Javascript files that are relevant only at dev or testing time, such
as definition of unit tests and un-minified versions of 3rd party libraries.

If I place these files in src/main/webapp, they would get included in the WAR
file and deployed to production, unless I customized the build tasks to exclude
them (the gradle war task specifically).

If I place them in a different directory I would have a custom directory
structure, and I probably would have to customize my environment to be able to
refer to them conveniently during development.

How do people typically deal with this type of setup?